# Proving of $\cos (\frac{2}{3})>\frac{\pi }{4}$

Tags: inequality

How can I prove that $$\cos \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)>\frac{\pi }{4}$$

Comment: $|\cos \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi }{4}| < 0.0005$, wow!

Comment: The solution that @1234 had posted (and AlexSilva incorrectly criticized) was indeed a proof. The Taylor of $\cos(x)$ is alternating, so it is enough to add terms until they are smaller than the precision needed, which is as Jihad is saying, the 4-th digit. The terms needed are not many, 6 are more than enough.

Comment: For the purposes of the proof, can we assume that the decimal expansion of $\pi$ is known to a reasonable accuracy? Because if it isn't, computing $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $4$ significant digits is likely part of the challenge.

Comment: @Pp.., I didn't criticize the Taylor approach posted by $@$1234, but the way he has computed the value of the expansion of $\text{cos}(2/3)$. Contrary to you have been saying here, he didn't take some terms of the expansion for solving the problem. Actually, he just substituted the value of the serie by the value of $\text{cos}(2/3)$. Did you really think that was a proof?

Answer (score 7):

When $0< x\leq1$ then
$$\cos x>1-{x^2\over2}+{x^4\over24}-{x^6\over 720}\ .$$
Putting $x:={2\over3}$ gives
$$\cos{2\over3}>{25781\over 32805}>{11\over14}\ .\tag{1}$$
When $0<y<1$ then
$$\sin y>y-{y^3\over6}+{y^5\over120}-{y^7\over5040}\ .$$
Putting $y:={11\over21}$ gives
$$\sin{11\over21}>{4540399710451\over9077486246640} \ >{1\over2}\ .$$
From $(1)$ we therefore obtain
$$\sin\left({2\over3}\cos{2\over3}\right)>\sin\left({2\over3}\cdot{11\over14}\right)=\sin{11\over21}>{1\over2}\ .$$
This implies ${2\over3}\cos{2\over3}>{\pi\over6}$, which is the same as $\cos{2\over3}>{\pi\over4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Use Carlson inequality
$$\arccos{x}>\dfrac{6\sqrt{1-x}}{2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+x}},0\le x<1$$

then let
$x=\frac{\pi}{4}$,then we have
$$\arccos{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}>\dfrac{6\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}}{2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi}{4}}}\approx 0.66741060\cdots>\dfrac{2}{3}$$
see [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%286%281-pi%2F4%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2F%282sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%281%2Bpi%2F4%29%29)
so
$$\cos{\dfrac{2}{3}}>\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Carlson inequality proof: you can google :Carlson inequality with arccosx

Comment: How many digits of $\pi$ does one need to know in order for this solution to work?

Comment: if this answer is Not what you want,I'm sure can't find good it

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is equivalent to:
$$ T_4\left(\cos\frac{1}{6}\right) > \frac{\pi}{4},\tag{1} $$
but since, using the Taylor series of the cosine function in a neighbourhood of zero:
$$ T_4\left(\cos\frac{1}{6}\right) > T_4\left(1-\frac{1}{72}\right),\tag{2} $$
it is sufficient to show that:
$$ 1-8\left(\frac{71}{72}\right)^2+8\left(\frac{71}{72}\right)^4 > \frac{\pi}{4}, \tag{3} $$
or:
$$ \pi < \frac{2638369}{839808} = [3; 7, 16, 1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 12, 1, 1, 1, 2]\tag{4}$$
that is true since $\pi =  [3; 7, \color{red}{15}, 1, 292,\ldots ]$.

Comment: Nice! Just to clearify, I guess that $T_4$ is a Chebyshev polynomial?

Comment: I think so,$\cos{(4x)}=T_{4}(\cos{x})$,but why $T_{4}(\cos{(1/6)})>T_{4}(1-1/72)?$

Comment: @math110: because in a neighbourhood of the origin $\cos z\geq 1-\frac{z^2}{2}$.

Comment: $T_{4}(x)$ is monotone increasing for $x$?

Comment: @math110: nope, but is it increasing in a neighbourhood of $1$ since we know its roots and the roots of the derivative.

Comment: Good, though still not free from the critique of numerical approximation. Almost like saying $$\cos \frac23 > \frac \pi 4 \iff [0; 1, 3, 1, 2,  \dots] > [0; 1, 3, 1, 1, \dots]$$